# Collapsing toolbar with ViewPager instead of ImageView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

So normally we have `Collapsible toolbars` with a `ImageView`, which vanishes when the toolbar is collapsed. Now, I want a `ViewPager` instead of the `ImageView`, so I simply replaced it with a `ViewPager` made a adapter and set it. But it doesn't seem to work. The toolbar stays blank with just the title text.

**My layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.meriawaaz.mygap.Activities.SingleIssueViewActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_collapsing_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout file?

Comment: My app has a `ViewPager` in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, so I know it's possible.  If you post your layout XML, I might be able to figure out the problem.  One hint I can give you: `ViewPager` doesn't handle a height of `wrap_content` very well, so if you're using that, just try setting a specific dp height to see if the `ViewPager` shows up then.

Comment: added :) please take a look